# Unable to add class attribute to the DOM element in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add a class to the dynamically created element in Angular

**sample-dom-manipulation.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample-dom-manipulation',
  templateUrl: './sample-dom-manipulation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample-dom-manipulation.component.css']
})
export class SampleDomManipulationComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('divMessages', {read: ElementRef}) private messages: ElementRef;

  text;
  constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
   const data = {message: 'WELCOME'};
   const pTag = this.renderer2.createElement('p');

   this.text = this.renderer2.createText(data.message);

   // append text to p element
   this.renderer2.appendChild(pTag, this.text);

   // I want to add the css-class to dynamically generated element!
   // But below line of code is not working.
   pTag.classList.add('bg-color');

   this.renderer2.appendChild(this.messages.nativeElement, this.text);

   // Below code works fine! but I don't want to do like this
   // this.renderer2.addClass(this.messages.nativeElement, 'bg-color');
  }
}
```

**sample-dom-manipulation.component.html**

```
<div #divMessages>

</div>

<p class="bg-color">
  COLORS
</p>
```

Please find the **[Stack-Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dom-manipulation-rk)** link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You have already applied bg-color class to ptag, what you want?

Comment: Because I want to dynamically generate elements and add come styling to it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4iz6cg

Comment: If anyone want's to edit please fork and edit the code

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you are not appending the correct element to the DOM.

Do this instead:

```
this.renderer2.appendChild(this.messages.nativeElement, pTag);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkcpw7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `renderer`, Use template binding

```
<div>
  <p *ngIf="condition" class="{{bgClass}} another-static-class"> {{ data?.message }} </p>
</div>
```

**Component code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  bgClass: string;
  data = { message: 'WELCOME' };
  condition = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.condition = true;
    this.bgClass = 'bg-color';
  }
}
```

[Fixed stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dafnt2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: But my goal is to achieve something different.